# Where is the Notifications log in Linux Mint Cinnamon?

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon

I'm looking for a log of the notifications applet in Linux Min Cinnamon `/usr/share/cinnamon/applets/notifications@cinnamon.org`

I'm not able to find any log file and actually don't know if it exists.
I'd like to be able to see the past notifications.

Answer (score 1):

There is a log in your home dir called `~/.cinnamon/glass.log` but it doesn't provide much information.

Looking at this related article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14025722/how-to-debug-cinnamon-applet suggests that there is no logs (because they are outputting to screen) but you can use the Linux Mint debugger called Looking Glass/Melange. Right click any cinnamon panel (taskbar for instance) and click troubleshoot and then Looking Glass.

Comment: The `~/.cinnamon/glass.log` report only what is going on during the startup. I need the log of the applet called **notifications**. The log should be something similar to the bash history log, for the terminal commands `~/.bash_history`.